# Reusable streams from file

Tags: file, scala, io, scala-collections, scala-2.10

How do I create a reusable Stream from a file in Scala? I have a huge file, and I want to use its contents multiple times, however I may not need to read the whole file completely

I have tried something like this, without success,

```
  // file iterator
  val f =  Source.fromFile("numberSeq.txt").getLines

  // construct stream from file iterator
  def numSeq: Stream[BigInt] = Stream.cons(BigInt(f.next()),numSeq)

  //test
  numSeq take 5 foreach println
  numSeq take 5 foreach println //the stream continues to print next file lines instead of going back to the first line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `toStream` right on your iterator:

```
scala> val f = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).toIterator.toStream
f: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> f take 5 foreach println
1
2
3
4
5

scala> f take 5 foreach println
1
2
3
4
5
```

In your concrete case, the problem was that you had the whole new stream on every `numSeq` call because of `def` used instead of `val`. You still need `def` for recursive definition, but don't forget to save it to the `val` before use:

```
scala> def numSeq: Stream[BigInt] = Stream.cons(BigInt(f.next()),numSeq)
numSeq: Stream[BigInt]

scala> val numSeq1 = numSeq
numSeq1: Stream[BigInt] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> numSeq1 take 5 foreach println
1
2
3
4
5

scala> numSeq1 take 5 foreach println
1
2
3
4
5
```

Example of wrong usage (notice `numSeq` instead of `numSeq1`):

```
scala> numSeq take 5 foreach println
6
7
8
9
10

scala> numSeq take 5 foreach println
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqLike$$anon$1.next(LinearSeqLike.scala:59)
  at .numSeq(<console>:14)
  ... 33 elided
```

Btw, there is more cute `#::` syntax for `cons`:

```
import Stream._
def numSeq: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(f.next()) #:: numSeq
val numSeq1 = numSeq
```

Finally, the version with better encapsulation:

```
val numSeq = { 
  def numSeq: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(f.next()) #:: numSeq 
  numSeq
}
```